# I have deployed a smart contract Onflow in testnet, how to update or delete them?

Tags: javascript, onflow-cadence

[image]Hi, I have deployed a smart contract in testnet, how to update or delete them? i tried both https://flow-view-source.com/ and CLI but both get this error

Comment: The bug updating happen when I added a new variable

Answer (score 0):

Adding new fields to an existing contract is not supported. The full list of changes allowed are here https://docs.onflow.org/cadence/language/contract-updatability

I would recommend just creating a new Testnet account and deploy the new contracts to that new address.